# Verbatim environment with gray background color and italics

Tags: listings, verbatim, backgrounds, italic

I want a verbatim environment with gray background color and italics(bold fonts may be used also). 
The `\lstlisting` can set background but can't set italics. The `\mdframed` combined with `\alltt` can make both of background color and italics available but will not break lines automatically. 
I can't find any other ways to do it. 
Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you need italics and bold, do you really need verbatim, do you need an italic monospaced font?

Comment: I want to use italic in a verbatim environment. But in some occasions, I just use bold font to stress something. So the bold is not necessary, but the italic with verbatim is what I need.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

you can change the font used by standard verbatim by redefining `\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily}` but mostly verbatim assumes you are going to use monospace font you could use

```
\maketletter
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\ttfamily\itshape}
\makeatother
```

but monospace italic is fairly horrible to read, so you could switch to

```
\maketletter 
\def\verbatim@font{\normalfont\itshape}
\makeatother
```

but that doesn't preserve column alignment (so isn't as verbatim as it could be)

In either case use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as in the default OT1 encoding verbatim only works with tt font (in other OT1 encoded fonts ascii characters such as `<` typeset as Spanish inverted punctuation signs)

Comment: what about the gray background?